# Compose two graphs based on a keyword, then remove the keyword

Tags: python, networkx

I have two graphs that I want to attach at a keyword 'root', then I want to remove the keyword 'root' leaving the two graphs attached.

`[word1] --- ['root'] --- [word2] -> [word1] --- [word2]`

I tried compose, but it doesn't work in the case where the graphs share more than 'root'.

One, there a way to compose on a key word. And two, how do I cut at the 'root' key word and attach the two nodes that were attached together.

edit:

I just realized that graphs are composed based on same node, so my real question is how to compose based on node value?

Comment: Can you give a more complete example?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just add an edge between the neighbors of 'root' since the two graphs are only connected by 'root' and 'root' always only has two neighbors. Then remove the 'root' node.

```
C.add_edge(C.neighbors('ROOT')[0],C.neighbors('ROOT')[1])
C.remove_node('ROOT')
```